# Why is the :hover selector not working on this SVG element?

Tags: css, svg, hover

When I use the selector `#apple:hover` to select an SVG element, the hover doesn't seem to be working. Why is this not working?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" display="none">
 <defs>
  <style>
  <![CDATA[
   #apple {
    fill: green;
   }

   #apple:hover {
    fill:red;
   }
   ]]>
 </style>
  <path id="apple" d="M38.6,30.1c0.1,8.6,7.5,11.4,7.6,11.5c-0.1,0.2-1.2,4.1-3.9,8.1c-2.4,3.5-4.8,6.9-8.7,7
  c-3.8,0.1-5-2.3-9.4-2.3c-4.3,0-5.7,2.2-9.3,2.3c-3.7,0.1-6.6-3.7-9-7.2c-4.9-7-8.6-19.9-3.6-28.6c2.5-4.3,6.9-7,11.7-7.1
  c3.7-0.1,7.1,2.5,9.4,2.5c2.2,0,6.4-3,10.9-2.6c1.9,0.1,7,0.7,10.4,5.6C44.5,19.5,38.5,23,38.6,30.1 M31.5,9.1c2-2.4,3.3-5.7,3-9.1
  c-2.9,0.1-6.3,1.9-8.4,4.3c-1.8,2.1-3.4,5.5-3,8.8C26.2,13.3,29.5,11.5,31.5,9.1"/>
 </defs>
 </svg>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 46.2 56.8" width="47" height="57">
  <use xlink:href="#apple"/>
 </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hover always work when I put the Id/class attribute on the <svg id="apple"> element  and not on the path. Can you try it out?

Comment: You can't use `hover` on paths I don't think if you made it into a link with no target page maybe that would work but it wouldn't be very practical.

Comment: i mean its not working if hover is defined in the internal styles of the referenced svg

Comment: @Webify hover is working on paths if i dont reference element by <use>. Just include inline svg. But why its not working with use and where can i read about it?

Comment: Because you are hovering over the `use` element not over the `apple`.Your css should read:  `use {fill: green;} use:hover {fill:red;}`

Comment: @MosiaThabo | That would work, but what if he/she wanted to style a specific path?

Comment: @Webify | My answer would disagree (if it could talk). The problem was the `<use xlink:href="#apple"/>`

Comment: @Tigerrrrr It never worked for me before as I have tried it. I can only answer with what has worked for me. In your case, I would have no solution.

Comment: @enxaneta | That would work too, but that's pretty much the same as svg (I think), if he/she wants to style that specific path element, it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MosiaThabo | Hopefully, my answer should help you too then.

Comment: @Tigerrrrr oh yes that would work aswell because its assigning a link to the svg which would work as its not a link, ok.

Comment: @Webify my english level is not pretty high yet in order to understand your answers.  Tiger showed me that hover doesnt work with use, okay... thats exactly what im trying to figure out -- why its not working? I read the spec and there is nothing about it. At least for my level of enlglish.

Answer (score 0):

Like most others (including me), you probably don't really care about the explanation, so I'll show you the answer first and the explanation afterwards.

Here's you answer:

```css
#apple {
  fill: green;
}

#apple:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="47" height="57" viewBox="0 0 46.2 56.8">
    <path id="apple" d="M38.6,30.1c0.1,8.6,7.5,11.4,7.6,11.5c-0.1,0.2-1.2,4.1-3.9,8.1c-2.4,3.5-4.8,6.9-8.7,7
    c-3.8,0.1-5-2.3-9.4-2.3c-4.3,0-5.7,2.2-9.3,2.3c-3.7,0.1-6.6-3.7-9-7.2c-4.9-7-8.6-19.9-3.6-28.6c2.5-4.3,6.9-7,11.7-7.1
    c3.7-0.1,7.1,2.5,9.4,2.5c2.2,0,6.4-3,10.9-2.6c1.9,0.1,7,0.7,10.4,5.6C44.5,19.5,38.5,23,38.6,30.1 M31.5,9.1c2-2.4,3.3-5.7,3-9.1
    c-2.9,0.1-6.3,1.9-8.4,4.3c-1.8,2.1-3.4,5.5-3,8.8C26.2,13.3,29.5,11.5,31.5,9.1"/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's your explanation:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 46.2 56.8" width="47" height="57">
    <use xlink:href="#apple"/>
</svg>
```

The problem was basically just, `<use xlink:href="#apple"/>`. You could've also just selected the svg or use element, but assuming you wanted to select that specific path, your best option is ^^.

Comment: Im talking about that css hover included in svg doesnt work in use that refernces it.